# NodeJS 12.x: Not found Error in AWS Greengrass

Tags: node.js, aws-iot-greengrass

I couldn't know where to tag my question properly, if I made a mistake I am so sorry. (I am new in stackoverflow).

I am trying to build an AWS Greengrass environment and I have a problem with installing the necessary packages.

I just installed NodeJS to my Ubuntu 20.04.1 in Virtual Machine:

```
VirtualBox@VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (12.19.0-deb-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 243 not upgraded.

VirtualBox@VirtualBox:~$ node --version
v12.19.0
```

So, I have NodeJS. Then I followed these commands:

```
cd /greengrass/greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.10.x
wget https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-greengrass-samples/raw/master/greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.10.x.zip
unzip greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.10.x.zip
cd greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.10.x
sudo check_ggc_dependencies | more
```

And now it displays this:

```
----------------------------Commands and software packages--------------------------
Python 2.7 version: 2.7.18
Python 3.7 version: 3.7.9
NodeJS 12.x: Not found
Java 8: Not found
```

I don't get it, I have NodeJS but why it says **Not found**

Do you have any opinion or suggestion to me?

I would be so happy if you can answer this, it took 3 hours for me to search but still couldn't solve..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it and I would like to share my solution for it;

I followed the steps here: https://github.com/aws/aws-greengrass-core-sdk-js

To download the NodeJS:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

After that you find `node` file under the `bin` directory.

Copied the file and pasted it to the desktop. The reason is that, we are not able to paste files under the `/usr/bin` directory, only root is allowed for this.

In the desktop, I changed the name of the file to `nodejs12.x`

And then opened a terminal in Desktop and run this command:

```
sudo cp nodejs12.x /usr/bin
```

The `cp` command is for giving the root acces. Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/921797/unable-to-paste-a-file-to-usr-folder

Now, the `node` file under the `bin` directory is copied under the `/usr/bin` directory and named as `nodejs12.x`. In the end, my problem is solved:

```
Python 2.7 version: 2.7.18
Python 3.7 version: 3.7.9
NodeJS version: 12.19.1
```

Comment: Why not just `sudo cp node nodejs12.x` while in `\usr\bin`?